# "then" starts a new sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I am writing some (mathematical) scientific paper. Which are correct:

"Let x=2, then x is in the set A."

or

"Let x=2. Then x is in the set A."

or

"Assume we have two sets, then one of them must be non-empty."

or

"Assume we have two sets. Then one of them must be non-empty."

or

"If t>0, then the function has no roots."

...

Comment: I can't come up with any logical or instructional meaning that might be intended by your *then one of them must be non-empty* example, regardless of punctuation. The only possible meanings of ***then*** I can imagine are 1) ***after** complying with the first instruction (making the assumption that there are two sets), **the next thing** to do is (that you must ensure one is non-empty),* or 2) ***because** you made the assumption that there are two sets, **it logically follows that** one is non-empty*. Neither seem like meaningful things to say, so what *do* you mean?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can't figure out what it is you say you don't get. In fact that sentence means (2); I'm totally in the dark regarding why you find (2) somehow less then meaningful.

Comment: 'Let x = 2 ... Then ...' must be taken as a shorter paraphrase of 'The variable x may take the value 2 (at this point of our argument). When x = 2, ...', or of 'When x has the value 2, this follows: ...'. Mathematical usages do not mirror non-mathematical ones precisely. However, I'd consider "Assume we have two sets. Then one of them must be non-empty." far better than "Assume we have two sets, then one of them must be non-empty." and "For t > 0, the function has no roots." better than "If t>0, then the function has no roots.".

Comment: Mainly just want to make sure about the punctuations.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich: I never did set theory at school, but I can't for the life of me see why it should logically follow that if I make the assumption I have two sets, one of them must be empty. The only intended meaning that makes sense to me there is *Assume we have two sets, **one of which** must be non-empty*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah, soo the problem was actually that you didn't see why what he was saying was true - that's very differennt from claiming you don't understand what he means! If you were certain that what he was saying was false and hence concluded he couldn't mean what he seemed to mean that would be one thing, but given that yuo say you never studied set theory you might be a little more careful about jumping to that conclusion. [continued...]

Comment: @FumbleFingers Here's an argument that I assure you is mathematically correct, whether it makes sense to you or not: Given two sets, at least one of them must be nonemtpy. Proof: If A and B are both empty then A=B, so A and B are _one_ set, not two.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Now, it would have been much better to say "If we have two disctinct sets..." But it's clear (to a mathematician - recall the stated _context_!) that that's what he meant, because if that's what he means then the statement is obviously true, while if he didn't mean "distinct" the statement is nonsense.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich: oic. I think. You mean we can't have two distinct sets which are *both* empty, because then they'd be the *same* set (there being only one possible instance of "the empty set")? Actually, no - I don't get that. If you said *Assume we have two numbers*, I can't see it logically follows that they can't both have the same numerical value. Although I *can* see that if a stage magician says *Pick any two cards,* it does pretty much follow that you won't pick the same card twice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't see why you think it matters whether you get it  nor not. You don't know any math, and you're not familiar with _standard_ mathematical usage. (Regarding the math, find the "ZFC axioms" on wikipedia and note the "axiom of extensionality"...)

Comment: @David C. Ullrich: I have an A level in Maths, and a degree in Language/Literature. I should think fairly obviously if the intended sense being referenced here isn't clear to someone like me, the question turns on domain-specific knowledge, and would be better asked on, say, [SO Maths,](https://math.stackexchange.com/) not a site devoted to *English* usages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If the idea that there is only one empty set is news to you then then you don't know _any_ of the _relevant_ math, A level or not. You _said_ you never studied any set theory. There's nothing unclear about the meaning of "Assume we have two sets, then at least one must be nonempty" - it means exactly what it says, regardless of whether you understood. (Your first comment today indicated that you _did_ understand what was intended, you just didn't see why it was true. He didn't ask about the math, he asked about the phrasing.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I just wanna make sure about the punctuation with respect to "Then" , so I came up with those random sentences... And read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory, if you are interested in

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to find a referee who objects to any of these;  they're all common. I wouldn't presume to say what's right or wrong here, but some of them *seem* wrong to me. But again I don't think it's that important; I know that when I'm trying to get students to write coherent mathematical English this is the last thing I worry about.

Seems to me that "then" wants an "if". "If P, then Q", fine. But "Assume P, then Q" strikes me as simply wrong. I think maybe the point is "then Q" is saying that  Q follows from a previous assertion, and "Assume P" does not actually assert anything; it's a command, not an assertion.

In any case, "Assume P, then Q" seems wrong to me. I can't  put my finger on exactly why, but "Assume P; then Q" and "Assume P. Then Q" bother me much less.

Comment: As tchrist has said, we are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers.

Comment: I think this is pretty much as good as it gets. I wouldn't go so far as to say the "reduced" construction *"Assume P, then Q"* is actually *wrong* with OP's values for P and Q - but as illustrated by my comments above, obviously if the reader doesn't already *know* that Q ***must logically follow*** from Q, he might not pick it up from the text as cited. (And if he needs to already know it in order to understand the assertion, why bother saying it at all?) In short, for *this* non-math specialist, it would be infinitely better with something like ***it must follow that** (one is non-empty)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers He _said_ he was writing a mathematical paper. I find it hard to understand how anyone could read "then" as meaning anyting other than "it follows that", but that certainly _is_ what it means in a mathematical context. Or philosophy, for that matter.

Comment: I know I'm really just repeating myself, but consider a similar construction that *doesn't* rely on the audience having highly domain-specific knowledge: *Assume it's Sunday, then you don't need to get up for work*. You might personally *prefer* a period there, but increasing numbers of people are quite happy to reduce it to a comma. Besides, that's just an orthographic convention which is meaningless in *real* (spoken) language anyway. The only issue I can see here is that lacking either/both ***if you / it follows*** or similar,  OP's construction is "over-reduced" for a broader audience.